# Can not install Indigo Desktop-Full Install

Tags: ros, gazebo, raspberrypi, armhf, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I tried to install Indigo Desktop-Full Install as instructed on this page http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu
However, it says I was missing ros-indigo-simulators, and so I tried sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-simulators, but it says
"ros-indigo-simulators : Depends: ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-pkgs but it is not installable".

I've done some digging, and know Indigo requires Gazebo2, but I can not get it anywhere. It appears that doing full desktop install of Indigo will automatically install Gazebo2 for me, but how can I install Indigo if it needs Gazebo2 as a prerequisite...

Oh and I've already tried using osrfoundation repository too, but it only offers Gazebo5.  Any ideas?

BTW I'm using xbuntu on raspberry pi 2.  When trying to install ROS on my ubuntu on PC works fine though.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210130/can-not-install-indigo-desktop-full-install/) by [harewei](https://answers.ros.org/users/22569/harewei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo is not built for armhf. For the Raspberry Pi 2 you should follow the ARM specific instructions at: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM

Not all the higher level packages are compatible with armhf processors. (About 1500 out of 1700 are armhf compatible) See [here](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/armhf/indigo.html) for the availability.

In general you're not going to have much luck running highly computationally intensive processes like Gazebo on the Raspberry Pi 2 anyway. I wouldn't recommend even trying to use a fully functional simulator on a small arm processor. We have demonstrated Gazebo running on platforms like the Jetson-TK1 but unless you have a very compelling use case it will likely be a lot more work than you want to make it useful.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0